# Доступ к данным из всего приложения

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как определить метод или переменную, чтобы данные с нее были доступны для вызова во всем приложении, данные будут динамически изменяться (вытягиваться из базы)?

Comment: А можно привести пример? И какую цель преследуете? Например, в /lib вы можете определить свой собственный класс и он будет доступен для вызова во всем приложении. Модели, вытягивающие данные из базы данных, доступны во всем приложении. Не очень понятно, что вызывает сложности.

Comment: Мне необходимо вернуть данные из бд, которые будут доступны везде, и в контроллерах и в представлениях итд. У меня есть таблица настроек, и настройки с этой таблицы используются в разных частях приложения. Мне нужно что бы был метод который возвращает либо все настройки, скажем при запуске приложения (не сервера) или будет при необходимости каждый раз запрос новый выполнять и возвращать одну настройку.

Comment: Т.е. хотите сломать MVC в MVC-фреймворке? Может тогда не использовать RoR, а взять Sinatra? Работать против соглашений в такой большой системе как Rails — очень дорого по времени и коду — вы будете бороться с фреймворком, а не использовать его преимущества. Если не убедил, рассмотрите возможность использования сервайсов или фасадов.

Comment: @cheops MVC, не MVC, концепция настроек программного продукта не обязана быть частью этого паттерна. Как продукту необязательно целиком быть построенным на Rails.

Comment: Пока что лучшее, что я видел для этой цели, это Sequel + static_cache + плагин pg_static_cache_updater, обновляющий кэши у всех при внесении изменений: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_static_cache_updater_rb.html Но на практике не пробовал.

Comment: @D-side Я как раз и говорю, что возможно и не стоит это делать в Rails. Фреймворк — это всегда шаг в определенную сторону. Если по пути, можно сэкономить время и усилия, если в другую сторону — можно наоборот потерять время и усилия. Sinatra и любой современный ruby-фреймворк, кстати, отлично подключается к рельсе через rack. Да и на самом rack можно писать.

Comment: @cheops это не какой-то там фреймворк, а с конкретной областью применения -- он про обслуживание веб-запросов для бизнес-задач. ТС же интересует совершенно несвязанная задача -- хранение в БД настроек и их чтение оттуда в произвольных местах кода приложения. Вовсе необязательно натягивать на эту задачу фреймворк и его нормы только потому, что проект на нём основан.

Comment: @D-side окей...